# How to make search Icon and back button icon disappear when clicking on different tab in TabLayout?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, searchview, android-tablayout

When you click on Search icon the searchView and keyboard appear, if the user decides to click on a different tab in TabLayout, I got the searchView and keyboard to disappear but I can't get the "Back" icon button and Search Icon button to disappear.

Here's what it looks when searchView was open and user clicks on a different Tab in TabLayout:

[image]

^ Also when user clicks on different tab in TabLayout for some reason Search Icon appears on left side instead of right side before the searchView open click.

Here's my code in menu_main.xml:

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/menuSearch"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:hint="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"

     />
```

Here's my MainActivity code inside `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu)`:

```
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);

         //   searchView.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.END));



          //  actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
          //  searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); 


           /* if (mViewPager.callOnClick()){
                actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                  searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
            }*/

            searchView.onActionViewCollapsed(); //closes searchView
```

**EDIT**

```
  if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0 || mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1 || mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
  menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch).collapseActionView();


  }






        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float offset, int offsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }



    });
```

The commented out code is what I tried but none of it seems to do anything. How do I get the "Back" icon button and Search icon button to also hide/disappear/close when I click on a different tab in TabLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
searchView.setIconified(true);
```

or

```
MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(menuItem)
```

or

```
searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
searchView.setQuery("", false);
searchView.clearFocus();
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to hide menuSearch because that's my search Icon?

Comment: I tried invalidateOptionsMenu(); but it didn't give me my desired effect.

Comment: When you call invalidateOptionsMenu(), system calls **onPrepareOptionsMenu()**. The method OnCreateOptionsMenu() is called only once during activity creation.

Comment: Actually, don't need invalidateOptionsMenu(). I just figured it out, I'll edit above the code I used. Maybe if you ever come across this issue, it may be helpful to you.

Comment: But this is ONLY if you used app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"  or instead of IfRoom you used Always